# how to select from a mysql table according to values in a second table

Tags: mysql

I have a table Email which contains emails, like:

```
EmailID DateStamp                Subject
8       2014-04-03 10:56:10.000  Subject of the Email
9       2014-02-25 08:52:10.000  Subject of the Email
10      2014-04-13 12:22:25.000  Subject of the Email
11      2014-02-15 11:18:16.000  Subject of the Email
12      2014-03-20 09:26:04.000  Subject of the Email
```

then I have a second table EmailDirection that connects users id and email id, where DirectionID is a numeric code that means: 1 = FROM; 2 = TO; 3 = CC and 4 = BCC

```
EmailID ProfileID DirectionID
10      72        1
10      91        2
10      58        2
10      57        3
10      24        3
10      44        3
```

I am looking to build a unique table where I have only four columns:

```
emailID    datestamp               sender    receiver
10         2014-04-13 12:22:25.000 72        91
10         2014-04-13 12:22:25.000 72        58
10         2014-04-13 12:22:25.000 72        57
10         2014-04-13 12:22:25.000 72        24
10         2014-04-13 12:22:25.000 72        44
```

where sender is the user that sent the email and receiver is a user that received the email, no matter if directly or as CC and BCC. My code so far is:

```
 SELECT Email.EmailID as 'id', Email.DateStamp as 'timed', 
 EmailDirection.ProfileID as 'sender' where profileID in (Select profileid from EmailDirection where directionid = 1), 
 EmailDirection.ProfileID as 'receiver' where profileid in (select profileid from EmailDirection where directionid != 1)
FROM Email, EmailDirection
WHERE Email.EmailID = EmailDirection.EmailID
```

but I get an error code 1064... I understand my problem is to specify the directionId for the sender and the receiver in the select statement, but I am not able to solve this simple puzzle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should approach this as multiple joins.  In particular, you want a separate join for the "from" and "to" parts of the email:

```
SELECT e.EmailID as id, e.DateStamp as timed, 
       edfrom.profileid as sender, edto.profileid as receiver
FROM EmailDirection edfrom join
     Email e
     on edfrom.emailid = e.emailid and ed.direction = 1 join
     EmailDirection edto
     on edto.emailid = e.emailid and ed.direction <> 1;
```

Two more comments.  First, only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Using them for column names will likely lead to problems.  Second, learn proper explicit `join` syntax.  As a rule:  Avoid commas in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables:

```
SELECT Email.EmailID as 'id', Email.DateStamp as 'timed', 
 sender.ProfileID as 'sender'  receiver.ProfileID as 'receiver' 
FROM Email join  EmailDirection sender on sender.EmailID = email.EmailID and sender.directionid=1
join  EmailDirection receiver on receiver.EmailID = email.EmailID and receiver.directionid!=1
```

!!! Untested !!!